# Switch from SharePoint to ASP.NET website with single login

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication

My company has a MOSS 2007 Enterprise (SharePoint 2007) website with users already setup. Everything is working fine. The users are setup in Active Directory. Now they want something really complex. I know how to do it in a few weeks in an ASP.NET website. That is my bread and butter. Here is what I would like to do.

I would like to write a new ASP.NET website using Window Authentication, and just have the users jump into the new application when they new this new ability. All of this has to be accessible from the internet. It is an External application. The external user accounts are in Active Directory already.

Will the identity still be the logged in user then they arrive at my new website?

NOTE: I do NOT what them to have to login again.

How can I do this?

NOTE: I am learning SharePoint Development. We have it. It is important to me to learn it. However, I am a little overwhelmed by it at the moment. We have 20+ developers, and NONE of us know anything about SharePoint. A consultant set it up, and a non developer is administrating it. In the future I will probably be the "man" in the future. That is a scary thought. SharePoint is something I want to know, however I have too much on my plate the next 2 months and NO help. I would like to get the application completed, and then move the code into SharePoint later if there is a need and a reason to do so. If there is no need, then we will keep it seperate.

Comment: Is your MOSS site also externally available? Provided both sites are on the same domain, and in the same app pool, I'd expect this to work as you want - however if your new site is on a different domain, then there's every chance ASP.NET would force a new login.

Comment: They will be on the same domain. SharePoint site is Ex: http://sp.mycompany.com and my asp.net website I would like to be at http://sp.mycompany.com/complexSubApp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on several factors - specifically will the domain name change when jumping between the two applications: e.g. moss.domain.com vs. asp.domain.com...

An effective way to deal with external Single Sign On (SSO) is to stand up an [ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/) that will act as the gateway to your servers, and it will handle all the sign on details. You can even have the credentials be used across subdomains or setup custom URL routing such that all visitors hit www.domain.com and based on the url (/sites/* would go to MOSS, /app/* would go to your ASP.NET site.